# CSS stylesheet not altering anything

Tags: css, html

I am starting out at writing my own website and following a few tutorials on HTML5 and CSS. I am using netbeans to create and edit my project.

Here is my index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="newcss" href="newcss.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is css</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css file, called newcss.css

```
p {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

I have my css file in the root folder of the webpage, same as the index file. All I am trying to do is change the colour of the text so I can see my style sheet is working. I am sure it is something really simple but can't seem to see it at the moment.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Mash

Comment: link attribute rel="stylesheet"

Comment: Just a notice: it might be easier on long run to use root relative links (/newcss.css) instead of location relative (newcss.css).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense I will bear it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [validator](http://validator.w3.org) (assuming you add an HTML 5 Doctype):

> Error Line 7, Column 57: Bad value newcss for attribute rel on element
>   link: The string newcss is not a registered keyword.
>
> ```
> <link rel="newcss" href="newcss.css" type="text/css">
> ```

To load a stylesheet you have to use the `stylesheet` relationship, not the `newcss` relationship (which doesn't exist).

Fix your `rel` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="newcss.css">
```

Change your `rel="stylesheet"`

Answer (score 0):

Change link rel:

```
<link rel="newcss" href="newcss.css" type="text/css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="newcss.css" type="text/css">
```